# How can I extract the user and type of the repository_dispatch trigger?

Tags: c#, github-actions, octokit.net

I am triggering a repository_dispatch event from C# bot on a github workflow. How can I extract the user and the event type (which is 'run_ba' in my case, I need the info beneath "Triggered via repository dispatch 6 days ago" label in the run example picture) that triggered the run using octokit.net?

[run example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbR8N.png)

I tried using GET on [https://api.github.com/repos/{repoOwner}/{repoName}/actions/runs](https://api.github.com/repos/%7BrepoOwner%7D/%7BrepoName%7D/actions/runs) ,but did not find what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi @MarianS, are you trying to read the user from withing a github actions workflow? If so, please show the relevant parts of your workflow.

Comment: Hello @rethab, I need to extract that data in the C# bot (so I can filter workflow runs based on the user that triggered the run -> slack bot and event type -> run_ba for cancel, restart purposes), not from the workflow, which would be something like this: `TRIGGERED_BY: "${{ github.actor }}" `

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my solution here, maybe it will help someone or someone will provide a better way to do this.

-Create another job in the workflow that creates annotations for the info that I need (check_run_id …)

e.g. echo “::notice title=RunId::${{ github.run_id }}”

-Using octokit to filter workflow runs based on status
-Using octokit retrieve the list of annotations based on the check_run_id from the list of workflow runs and the checksuite that is attached to annotations job.